# Cannot convert value of type String to specified type NSManagedObjectContext Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3.2

I need Help. While conversion from Swift 2.3 -> 3.2 I received below error. I'm not able to resolve this error.

**Error :** **Cannot convert value of type String to specified type NSManagedObjectContext**

Below is my coding stuff, where I'm facing some issues.

```
class FileManager {
    class func directoryForPersistentStorage(_ directoryName: String) -> Foundation.URL {
        var urlToReturn: Foundation.URL!

        let libraryDirectory = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [String]).first
        if let cLibraryDirectory = libraryDirectory {
            let expectedDirectoryPath = (cLibraryDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(directoryName)
            let fileManager = Foundation.FileManager.default
            var isDirectory = ObjCBool(false)
            if (!fileManager.fileExists(atPath: expectedDirectoryPath, isDirectory: &isDirectory) || !isDirectory.boolValue) {
                do {
                    try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: expectedDirectoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                } catch _ {
                }
            }
            urlToReturn = URL(context: expectedDirectoryPath) // Above mentioned #Error is Here

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: expectedDirectoryPath) {
                do {

                    try urlToReturn.setTemporaryResourceValue(true as AnyObject?, forKey: URLResourceKey.isExcludedFromBackupKey)

                } catch _ {
                }
            }
        }
        return urlToReturn
    }

    class func persistentFileURL(_ name: String, enclosingDirectoryName: String) -> Foundation.URL {
        let directoryURL = self.directoryForPersistentStorage(enclosingDirectoryName)
        let urlPath = directoryURL.path
        let filePath: String = (urlPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(name)

        return URL(context: filePath) // Above mentioned #Error is Here
    }
}
```

Error1 : Cannot convert value of type String to specified type NSManagedObjectContext**

Note : URL is separate Class declared to handle this : [URL_Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VUYa.png) & [extension of URL Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D6k0.png)

Please help me. I'm very new to iOS. Not able to understand this type of error.

Comment: in which line you got error?

Comment: Line which is marked with this comment => // Above mentioned #Error is Here

Comment: Only Two same errors are there. on both the lines

Comment: have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856991/cannot-convert-value-of-type-string-to-specified-type-nsmanagedobjectcontext-wh?rq=1

Comment: Yeah I have check that one... have resolved that error. But this seems to be more problematic.

Comment: My error is same as there Error2. Which is not yet resolved even there.

Comment: just clean and build

Comment: Yeah, Tried it many times...but not able to resolve it.

Comment: which code you are use hive me any reference

Comment: It's a old Swift project which is in Swift 2.3. But seems due to latest apple policy, I have to convert it into latest version. So for that I have converted it into Swift 2.3->3.2. Then I tried 3.2->4.1.  But before conversion app was running properly, without any errors.

Comment: In Swift 3+ `URL` is an internal struct as a replacement for Foundation `NSURL`. You are strongly discouraged from using the name for an arbitrary type,

Comment: Hi @vadian then please suggest me some solution so that it will work.

Comment: You have to refactor the entire code to get rid of all `NS...` Foundation stuff and the ugly `as AnyObject` bridge casts.

Comment: Is it correct, that URL is your custom class?

Comment: Yes it is correct, that URL is my custom class